# extract data from column based on subset of data from other other column

Tags: excel

This is how my data looks like:

```
C1  C2  C3
1   1   a
2   2   a
3   3   a
4   4   a
7   5   a
8   6   a
9   7   a
10  8   a
    9   a
    10  b
```

You see that C1 is a subset of column C2. I want now to extract only the data from C2 - together with the corresponding value from C3 - that matches C1. The extracted data just needs to be copied to another column

Could someone give me a hand?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Take a look at the `VLOOKUP` formula, that should help you here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data in C1 starts from A2, do the following:

1. Type in cell D2 (column C4): `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2,$B:$C,1,0),"")`
2. Type in cell E2 (column C5): `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2,$B:$C,2,0),"")`
3. Autofill both formulas.

This will give you what you want, missing values will be shown as blanks. If you want concatenate both parts of out - just put the aggregate formula `=ISERROR(...)&ISERROR(...)` to any column row 2 you like.

Sample file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qglyxmu3tkfxy7g/DataExtract2Cols.xlsx